# Tensorflow: Error while restoring model

Tags: tensorflow

I am not sure how to use this model to obtain predictions. The code for the model is below:

```
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2, name = "layer_2")

loss_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(
                 weights=weights['out'],
                 biases=biases['out'],
                 labels=y,
                 inputs=layer_2,
                 num_sampled=int(num_words * .10),
                 num_true=1,
                 num_classes=num_words))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss_function)
save_path = saver.save(sess, "C:\\Users\\gowth\\Documents\\model.ckpt")
print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)
```

To restore the model and access the variable `layer_2`, I am using this code:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("C:\\Users\\gowth\\Documents\\model.ckpt.meta")

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('"C:\\Users\\gowth\\Documents\\'))
    print("Model restored.")
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    ima, lab = next_batch(1)
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("x:0")
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("y:0")
    feed_dict={x: ima, y: lab}
    prediction=graph.get_tensor_by_name('layer_2:0')
    print (sess.run(prediction,feed_dict))
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: expected bytes, NoneType found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-6c2213900ab9> in <module>()
      4 
      5 with tf.Session() as sess:
----> 6     saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('"C:\\Users\\gowth\\Documents\\'))
      7     print("Model restored.")
      8     graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

In the `Documents` folder, the following files are present:
`model.ckpt.meta, checkpoint, model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001, model.ckpt.index`

In general, can you comment on if this approach of evaluation is correct or not.

Comment: Have you checked what `latest_checkpoint` returns and have a look at the path closely to make sure you don't include special characters like double quotes.

Comment: it turns out the error was that I accidentally put special characters in the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is just the double quotation mark before your path. Otherwise you should probably check, whether the path in the checkpoint file itself is correctly pointing to the model file.

Comment: it turns out the error was that I accidentally put special characters in the path